# How to convert HTML character NUMBERS to plain characters in PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-entities

I have some HTML data (over which I have no control, can only read it) that contains a lot of Scandinavian characters (å, ä, ö, æ, ø, etc.). These "special" chars are stored as HTML character **numbers** (æ = `&#230;`). I need to convert these to the corresponding actual character in PHP (or JavaScript but I guess PHP is better here...). Seems like `html_entity_decode()` only handles the "other" kind of entities, where æ = `&#aelig;`. The only solution I've come up with so far is to make a conversion table and map each character number to a real character, but that's not really super smart...
So, any ideas? ;)

Cheers,
Christofer

Comment: In what way isn't `html_entity_decode()` working for you? What are you passing as the charset parameter? Seems to work for me...

Comment: Yeah turns out it works perfectly fine... if you read the manual properly ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `html_entity_decode()` should work just fine. What happens when you try:

```
echo html_entity_decode('&#230;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
&#NUMBER;
```

refers to the unicode value of that char.

so you could use some regex like:

```
/&#(\d+);/g
```

to grab the numbers, I don't know PHP but im sure you can google how to turn a number into its unicode equivalent char.

Then simply replace your regex match with the char.

**Edit**: Actually it looks like you can use this:

```
mb_convert_encoding('&#230;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP manual page on `html_entity_decode()`, it gives the following code for decoding numeric entities in versions of PHP prior to 4.3.0:

```
  $string = preg_replace('~&#x([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $string);
  $string = preg_replace('~&#([0-9]+);~e', 'chr("\\1")', $string);
```

As someone noted in the comments, you should probably replace `chr()` with `unichr()` to deal with non-ASCII characters.

However, it looks like `html_entity_decode()` really should deal with numeric as well as literal entities.  Are specifying an appropriate charset (e.g.,UTF-8)?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't got the luxury of having multibyte string functions installed, you can use something like this:

```
<?php

    $string = 'Here is a special char &#230;';

    $list = preg_replace_callback('/(&#([0-9]+);)/', create_function(
        '$matches', 'return decode(array($matches[2]));'
    ), $string);

    echo '<p>', $string, '</p>';
    echo '<p>', $list, '</p>';

    function decode(array $list)
    {
        foreach ($list as $key=>$value) {
            return utf8_encode(chr($value));
        }
    }


?>
```